# Ball on a string

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, string, centripetal-force

A ball is attached to a string on a pole (i.e. Totem Tennis). If you hit the ball harder tangentially and horizontally, what will happen to the centripetal force, velocity and radius? Intuitively it seems the radius of motion will initially increase in an outwards spiral before an inwards spiral back towards the pole, but I'm looking for an explanation using physics concepts.

Comment: It's not clear what initial situation you're postulating. Is the ball already revolving?

Answer (score 0):

If the ball is already revolving in a stable circle,  and you add tangential velocity to it, it will have more energy than is needed for the circular orbit it started with. It's going to start to oscillate, going higher and losing speed, swinging back down and gaining speed back, and so on. It's analogous to an object in orbit in space (but not the same since it's not moving in a plane in this case)

Comment: Thank you for the response. To clarify, in this situation the ball is already revolving. However, if I hit the ball and it begins to revolve, would it keep circling forever in the absence of retarding forces? I ask this because Newton's First Law describes objects moving in a straight line, but I'm not sure whether this also applies to circular motion. Additionally, in circular motion there is always a net force (i.e. centripetal force).